# `ValueError: 1-2 args execution context is supported` on call to `bpy.ops.outliner.show_hierarchy` in Blender 4.0.1

Tags: scripting

I have the following code which I use for expanding all collections in the outliner

```
def toggle_collection_collapse(state):
    area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == 'OUTLINER')
    bpy.ops.outliner.show_hierarchy({'area': area}, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    for i in range(state):
        bpy.ops.outliner.expanded_toggle({'area': area})
    area.tag_redraw()

class Expand_All(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Expand All"
    bl_idname = "my.expand_all"

    def execute(self, context):
        toggle_collection_collapse(1)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

This used to work on Blender 3.6.5 but now in 4.0.1 I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/models.blend/Text", line 218, in execute
  File "/Users/user/models.blend/Text", line 195, in toggle_collection_collapse
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 106, in __call__
    C_exec, C_undo = _BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 60, in _parse_args
    raise ValueError("1-2 args execution context is supported")
ValueError: 1-2 args execution context is supported
```

Seems like the problem is when calling this line `bpy.ops.outliner.show_hierarchy({'area': area}, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')`

How I can fix this?

Comment: It looks like this method doesn't work with a number of operators. For example, the operator `bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` causes a critical error in Blender and it closes. And so far unfortunately i have not found any information on how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blender dev team added a new API for overriding context some time ago:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context

Overriding context should be implemented this way, context attribute was deprecated and [disabled in 4.0](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/ac263a9bce53e190d07d679a058a230e91e722be). Info in [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API#Breaking_changes):

> Blender Operators (bpy.ops)
> Remove the context override argument to
> bpy.ops in favor of context.temp_override(..) ([ac263a9bce](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/ac263a9bce53e190d07d679a058a230e91e722be))

`bpy.ops.some_ops({"a": a, "b": b})` need change to `with bpy.context.temp_override(a=a, b=b): bpy.ops.some_ops()`

```
import bpy

def toggle_collection_collapse(state, context):
    area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == 'OUTLINER')

    with context.temp_override(area=area):
        bpy.ops.outliner.show_hierarchy('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        for i in range(state):
            bpy.ops.outliner.expanded_toggle()
        area.tag_redraw()

class Expand_All(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Expand All"
    bl_idname = "my.expand_all"

    def execute(self, context):
        toggle_collection_collapse(1, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(Expand_All)

    # test call
    bpy.ops.my.expand_all()
```