Blender save Collections as separate blend file for blender 4.2
I have this script for saving collections as separate blend files. But it doesnt work for blender files above blender version 3.6. How can I use this script for blender 4.2? What do I need to change?
import bpy
import os


# folder containing blend files
ip_path = "C:\\Blender Projects\\bridge\\"
ip_fname = "bridge_002.blend"

# target folder
op_path = "C:\\Blender Projects\\bridge\\temp\\"

blendfiles = [ip_fname,]

def clear_cur_colls():
    while len(bpy.data.collections) > 0:
        bpy.data.collections.remove(bpy.data.collections[0])
    override = bpy.context.copy()
    override["area.type"] = ['OUTLINER']
    override["display_mode"] = ['ORPHAN_DATA']
    bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge(override)

def get_coll_names(assets_path):
    names = []
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(assets_path) as (data_from, data_to):
        names = [name for name in data_from.collections]
    return names

for file in blendfiles:
    # prep to make a folder based on blend file name
    filepath = os.path.join(ip_path, file)

    # make a folder based on blend file name to store new files
    if not os.path.isdir(op_path):
        os.mkdir(op_path)
    # get each object from blend file
    colls = get_coll_names(filepath)
    for coll in colls:
        # clear the current file
        clear_cur_colls()
        # append the object
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=file, directory=str(filepath)+"\\Collection\\", filename=coll)
        # save blend file
        bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=os.path.join(op_path, coll+".blend"))

clear_cur_colls()


The override method need change:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305388/valueerror-1-2-args-execution-context-is-supported-on-call-to-bpy-ops-outlin/305390#305390

AFAIK bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge need not be overriden ? Have you tried simply running
bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge(do_local_ids=True, do_linked_ids=True, do_recursive=True)
